# pandas v0.17.1 not working with py2exe

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt4, py2exe

I Have a problem with python pandas v0.17.1. I upgraded from v0.16.2.
System:

Win10 x64, Python 3.4 64Bit, using PyCharm Community Edition for coding.
(numpy 1.9.3+mkl)

I'm using py2exe to create a stand-alone of a statistics program, using pandas to hold the data, matplotlib for plotting and pyqt4 for everything related to gui.

Since i upgraded pandas, the created .exe from py2exe doesn't work anymore. After doubleclick or start from commandline nothing happens. No Errors, no Errorlog file or similar, no 'window flashing' open and close again. just nothing.

I uninstalled pandas and reinstalled (fresh install) it via pip. Same problem.
I just downgraded pandas to v0.16.2 again. Everything works fine now (with v0.16.2). No other changes made.

For the sake of testing i created a simplest program as possible, only an empy pyqt mainwindow and whats needed to start the programm. works fine witout pandas. After 'import pandas' nothing happens anymore (with v0.17.1).

Somebody knows whats going on? Do i have to tweak my setup.py for the new pandas version? Because i dont get any error, i cannot check whats wrong.

main.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import matplotlib
#import pandas


class app(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    programm = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = app()
    window.show()
    eventloop = programm.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

setup.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

path_to_source = r'path to dir' # replace with your working directory

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {
                          'includes': ['sip'],
                          'excludes': [],
                          'optimize': 2, 
                          'compressed' : False, 
                          'packages': ['encodings']
                          #'skip_archive': True
                          }},
    zipfile = None, 
    windows = [{"script": path_to_source + r"/main.py"}]
)
```

Just uncomment the import statement of pandas and nothing works anymore with v0.17.1.
The 'dist' directory gets created with a the same files as before.
I tried to 'include' pandas in setup.py but no effect. Dont know what to do to solve this. Are some dll's needed in the setup.py now?

Sorry for my bad english.
ps: In PyCharm, everything works fine, it's only the .exe that does not work.
ps2: Tested the same with my Win7 installation, same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was my AVAST Anti-Virus. It's 'deepscreen' feature started the programm in the background as a sandbox and analysed the .exe but never informed me about it running in the back (no info baloon etc.).

By chance, i had it deactivated while looking into Calvin's Answer.

It works on both, my PC and Laptop now, without any changes. Just deactivated AVAST 'deepscreen' feature while using the .exe created py py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue as well.  What I found was that a packaged called 'nbformat' caused the py2exe script to fail.  I added this package into my excludes list and the script ran successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check this in a few days and will report the result.